# Implement top value per group sort in bash

Tags: bash, scripting

Using bash, I'd like to sort and filter a list to retain only the last patch version (top value) per minor version (per group). For example:

```
$ cat data | sort -Vr
3.10.1
3.10.0
3.3.10
3.3.2
3.3.1
3.2.0
3.1.0
3.0.3
3.0.2
3.0.1
3.0.0
```

I'd like to get this result:

```
3.10.1
3.3.10
3.2.0
3.1.0
3.0.3
```

How to do it?

Comment: Is the content of `data` guaranteed to be ordered by `major desc, minor desc, patch desc`?

Comment: The `data` content is guaranteed to be of the form `major.minor.patch`, but not sorted. However, `sort -Vr` then guarantees that order as far as I know...

Comment: I was blind, I didn't see the `| sort -Vr` although it's almost impossible to miss it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use another sort with `-u`

```
sort -Vr data | sort -ru -t. -Vk1,2
```

- `-t.` uses a dot as the field separator
- `-k1,2` sorts by the first two fields, i.e. it ignores the patch version
- `-u` means "unique", i.e. it only prints the first occurrence for each group that sorts the same